# Animate Page Transition with React Router and CSSTransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to learn css transition groups with react.  When I run the following code, my page will fade-in.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import Config from './Settings/Config';
import App from './Components/App';
import About from './Components/About';
import Career from './Components/Career';

const CONFIG = new Config();
const CORP = CONFIG.baseNameCorp;
const LEASING = CONFIG.baseNameLeasing;

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({basename:CONFIG.baseName})

render((
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName="example"
    transitionAppear={true}
    transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
    transitionLeaveTimeOut={1000}>

  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path={CORP} component={App}>
    <Route path={CORP+"career"} component={Career} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

However, what I really wanted to do is when I go from the about url to the career url, I want the about us component to fade out and for the career component to fade in, and vice versa.  So i tried doing this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import Config from './Settings/Config';
import App from './Components/App';
import About from './Components/About';
import Career from './Components/Career';

const CONFIG = new Config();
const CORP = CONFIG.baseNameCorp;
const LEASING = CONFIG.baseNameLeasing;

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({basename:CONFIG.baseName})

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path={CORP} component={App}>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="example"
        transitionAppear={true}
        transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
        transitionLeaveTimeOut={1000}>
          <Route path={CORP+"about"} component={About} />
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="example"
        transitionAppear={true}
        transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
        transitionLeaveTimeOut={1000}>
          <Route path={CORP+"career"} component={Career} />
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

But this code seems to have no effect.  When I go between the about url and career url, the two components just abruptly hide and show. How do I get the fade transition to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the ReactCSSTransition in the main App component and render transitions to its children using

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link></li>
    </ul>

     <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="example"
            transitionAppear={true}
            transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
            transitionLeaveTimeOut={1000}>
              {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                  key: location.pathname
              })}
     </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
    )
  }

}
```

And then have your routes written normally.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import Config from './Settings/Config';
import App from './Components/App';
import About from './Components/About';
import Career from './Components/Career';

const CONFIG = new Config();
const CORP = CONFIG.baseNameCorp;
const LEASING = CONFIG.baseNameLeasing;

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({basename:CONFIG.baseName})

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path={CORP} component={App}>
      <Route path={CORP+"about"} component={About} />
      <Route path={CORP+"career"} component={Career} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```